# Acer 5720 network connection

Tags: networking, windows-7, drivers, compatibility

Moved

https://superuser.com/questions/547278/acer-aspire-5720-network-driver

I Know this probably isn't the best site to post this problem but i don't know which is...

I have an acer aspire 5720 freshly formatted to win7 x64

I tried installing the drivers found on the
 drivers page on the acer website however they either install and end up doing nothing or fail to install claiming that the hardware is not present. Wifi and wired internaet atm are not working.

Thanks

Comment: Describing a problem as something "not working" is not helpful. What shows up in Device Manager? What goes wrong when you try to use them?

Comment: This is now a programming related question, consider moving to `SuperUser site`

Comment: Please don't repost next time but wait for migration.